# Unity: Scene overlapping on real device

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game where I use the following code on my Start button in my Menu scene and for the Restart button once my player dies in the Game scene. The problem is occurring only when I play the game on my real device with the Build & Run Unity setting. I have two buttons that move my player, after pressing them a few times the movement would lag and the Menu scene would overlap over my Game scene while playing. It occurs every time the game starts. More directly put. I am playing and suddenly a black background and two big START and SETTINGS buttons flash during my playing and lag my controls and then they go away. Does anyone have ideas where this issue might arise from?

```
 public void LoadScene(string sceneName)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strange, it shouldn't happen.

However, try using the `LoadSceneAsync` with this code and see if the bug still happens:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;

public class ScenesManager : MonoBehaviour {    

    IEnumerator loadScene;
    public float loadingProgress;

    public void LoadScene(string levelName) {
        loadScene = AsyncLoad(levelName);
        StartCoroutine(loadScene);
    }

    private IEnumerator AsyncLoad(string levelName) {
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(levelName, LoadSceneMode.Single);
        asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;

        while (!asyncLoad.isDone) {
            loadingProgress = Mathf.Clamp01(asyncLoad.progress);
            asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = false;
            if (asyncLoad.progress == 0.9f) {
                asyncLoad.allowSceneActivation = true;
            }
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the maybe stupid question. It says loadScene  and loadingProgress do not exist. Do I need to add them as something? I haven't encountered LoadSceneAsync before.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to write the declaration of those two variables: `loadScene` is an `IEnumerator`, as coroutines are in Unity, while `loadingProgress` is simply a `float` that you can use to keep track of the loading progress, in order to use it for example with a loading bar.
I've corrected the code.